What is causing this 'close resource' error with tests of KV in Deno 2?
I have some pretty simple Deno tests around retrieving some data from a Kv database. Using beforeAll I open a new DB and add some test data. Then using afterAll I close and delete the DB file.
When I run the tests, they all pass, but the describe level test fails because of this error.
getUserActions => https://jsr.io/@std/testing/1.0.4/_test_suite.ts:218:10
error: Leaks detected:
  - "database" was created during the test, but not cleaned up during the test. Close the resource before the end of the test.

I can verify that the the Kv data is actually deleted by just looking at the location where it shortly lived. What am I missing here to ensure the test framework understands that the db files have been deleted.
In other words, what is causing this error?
Here are some relevant file snippets.
// The Test
import { expect } from "jsr:@std/expect";
import { afterAll, beforeAll, describe, it, } from "jsr:@std/testing/bdd";

describe("getUserActions", () => {
  let kv: Deno.Kv;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    kv = await Deno.openKv("./test_data");
    await seedTestUserActionData();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await kv.close();
    console.log("start delete");
    await deleteTestKv();
    console.log("end delete");
  });

// some tests follow
}

// database deletion functions
export async function deleteTestKv(
  dbPath: string = "./test_data"
): Promise<void> {
  await closeDb(dbPath);

  try {
    // Check if file exists before attempting deletion
    await Deno.stat(dbPath);
    await Deno.remove(dbPath);
    await Deno.remove(dbPath + "-shm");
    await Deno.remove(dbPath + "-wal");
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Deno.errors.NotFound) {
      console.log(`Database file ${dbPath} not found`);
    } else {
      console.log("Remove error:", error);
    }
  }
}

async function closeDb(dbPath: string): Promise<void> {
  try {
    // First try to close any existing connections
    const kv = await Deno.openKv(dbPath);
    await kv.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Close error:", error);
  }
}


Please [edit] the post to include a single, direct question. (See [ask].) If your question involves existing code, be sure to also include a [mre].

It turned out that I wasn't closing the connection in the seedTestUserActionData function. That was the missing piece.

Can you clarify what that means? Everywhere you call openKV, you must immediately close it before the method exits?

For testing purposes, I believe that is correct. The 'leaks detected' error in the original post was caused by the connection staying open even after the tests ended. As I have continued to work with Deno KV, I have made sure to close the connection after distinct actions, like adding or deleting a record.
I refactored the original code. I removed the kv connection from the describe block all together and relied on the connection from database seeding function, which included closing the connection.

Okay, thanks. Here is where I ended up, by using a callback.
I was surprised that -- except for the setter -- I didn't even need to make the method async.
  private async withKv<T>(callback: (kv: Deno.Kv) => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    const kv = await Deno.openKv();
    try {
      return await callback(kv);
    } finally {
      kv.close();
    }
  }

  async store_value(key: string, value: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.withKv(async (kv) => {
      await kv.set([this.prefix, key], value);
    });
  }

  retrieve_value(key: string): Promise<string | undefined> {
    return this.withKv(async (kv) => {
      const result = await kv.get([this.prefix, key]);
      return result?.value as string | undefined;
    });
  }

